# Rename file names based on a pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a lot of data with file names like this:

```
combination.2005.0801.txt
combination.2005.0802.txt 
...
combination.2005.0830. txt
```

What should I do if I want to rename that files to be like this?

```
20100801.txt  
20100802.txt
...
20100803.txt
```

I already tried to use the following script, but unfortunately the script is not working.

```
rename 's/combination.(.*).(.*).txt/$1.txt/' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When using (Perl compatible; or more general, most) regular expressions, you'll have to keep in mind that `.` will match any character; not just periods (but also only one character unless there's a quantifier).

The following is untested, but i'd probably try to use this solution [based on this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961255/rename-files-using-a-regex-with-bash):

```
$ for old in ./combination*.txt; do
    new=$(echo $old | sed -r 's/combination\.([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]]+)\.txt$/\\1\\2.txt/')
    mv -v "$old" "$new"
  done
```

Keep in mind that this is untested and might break. You could also use `echo` rather than `mv` to test the whole thing first. :)

Comment: I already tried to use that command. But the result:

Comment: I already tried to use that script. But the result = new: command not found. And then I tried change the line 2 (new = .....) by deleted the space (new=.....) and when I ran the script, the result = ./combination.2005.0801.txt ./combination.2005.0801.txt. It is mean the script is not working.

Comment: My bad, try the updated script.

Comment: The result by using the updated script= -v ./combination.2005.0801.txt ./\1\2\.txt

Answer (score -1):

```
$ for i in combination*.txt; do
   mv $i $(echo $i | awk -F\. '{print $2$3"."$4}'); 

done
```

Comment: thx, we edited it at the same sec :)

Comment: Why do you believe that you need the ``\`` (backslash) between the `-F` and the **`.`**?